# Does hasStableIds and getItemId have any significance if DiffUtil is used?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, identity, android-diffutils

We are using `DiffUtil.CalculateDiff` with a custom `DiffUtil.Callback` to handle changes to the underlying data.

- The identity of our elements is rather complex, and that's why we are using custom equality check in `areContentsTheSame` and `areItemsTheSame`.
- However, the adapter has two things `hasStableIds` and `getItemId`.

The problem is that `getItemId` returns a `long` and the identity of our elements can't be conflated into a `long` in a stable way (although otherwise stable considering our custom equality check in diffutil's callback.

**The question is this:**

What to do with `hasStableIds` and `getItemId` in this case, and are those at all used when DiffUtil is pushing changes to the adapter?

Comment: https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what has stables actually does in the background but it is used for keeping the elements in the order and remove any buggy stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunatelly it doesn't help much. The point is: I know what hasStableIds does when using regular notifyDataSetChanged is used with adapter. But my question is specifically whether this is needed, or used at all when diffutil is used.